# Как задать max_connections при установке webhook telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, api, бот

В командной строке windows можно установить

```
curl -F "url=https://логин:пароль@адрес_сервера" https://api.telegram.org/botТокенБота/setWebhook -k
```

Как установить параметр max_connections ?